# Making a dialog box that allows user to select file

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I want to make a button in `Java` such that when user clicks it a box opens that allows the user to select a file. Note:  For my application , I only need the file path. I do not need the exact file.  Is there a way to do this in `Java using swing` etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `JFileChooser`. Write following code inside your `actionPerformed` for the Button.

```
JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
    jfc.showDialog(null,"Please Select the File");
    jfc.setVisible(true);
    File filename = jfc.getSelectedFile();
    System.out.println("File name "+filename.getName());
```

Comment: onClick or actionPerformed(), onClick is used to do things automatically, without even user clicking the button. Am i Wrong ?

Comment: *"I only need the file path."* - the OP.  In that case, be sure to set the file chooser to browse for directories only.

Answer (score 0):

```
'private void OpenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        try {
              // What to do with the file, e.g. display it in a TextArea
            textarea.read( new FileReader( file.getAbsolutePath() ), null );
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                  System.out.println("problem accessing file"+file.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("File access cancelled by user.");
        }
}'
```